# How does an object literal parameter declaration in a Typescript arrow function work?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions, object-literal

I've come across the following Typescript idiom quite a bit in an application.

```
interface something {
    comment: string;
}

const f = <something>({ data: result }) => result.comment;

console.log(f({ data: { comment: "Hi Mom"} }));
```

which produces "Hi Mom" on the console as expected.

I've got two basic questions:

- Effectively, this seems to be saying, "Take the value of whatever the data field of the object that I pass you contains, call it `result` and cast it as a `something`", but I don't understand how this accomplishes that. How is `result` being bound appropriately in the function call?
- Secondly, tslint complains that `something` is a shadowed name. As far as I can see, it's a typecast, and I don't see how a typecast defines a name at all, let alone one that's shadowed.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: `<something>` is not a type assertion in this case but the introduction of a generic function type parameter, like the `T` in  `function f<T>(){}`.  It's not doing anything useful at all in that example, and is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: The answer to your first question is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names), a stage 4 proposal for JavaScript (and not specific to TypeScript)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was after. May I suggest you turn these comments into an answer, so that I can credit you properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take the value of whatever the data field of the object that I pass you contains, call it result

Is correct, it's called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

> and cast it as a something

Apparently, in this example, it's just a mistake, it does nothing there. These are called [Generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). I can only say that example should look like that, so it uses generics in the right way:

```
interface something {
  data: {
    comment: string;
  }
}

const f = <T extends something>({ data: result }: T) => result.comment;

console.log(f({ data: { comment: "Hi Mom"} }));
```

> tslint complains that something is a shadowed name

That's right because `something` is was defined as an interface, and as a generic type, so tslist complains

Hope it was clear :)